# Build my cross platform applications using intel XDK without cloud support?

Tags: intel-xdk, intel-xdk-contacts

I recently start using Intel XDK. I found that for each platform creation my code will go to Intel cloud center to perform the build. Its a feature mentioned at [Product Brief Intel® XDK](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/managed/56/86/Intel%20XDK%20Product%20Brief.pdf).

Can I build that locally? I mean can I build locally in my system itself using Intel XDK? If so, then how?

Comment: do you use the intel xdk api? if not you can build your app localy with cordova\phonegap

Comment: yes i am using xdk api.With this frame work how can i build off line.

Answer (score 1):

are you afraid of intel knowing your code? in cordova\html5 app your code is available to anyone just get the apk from the store open with winrar and your code is there

if you want offline build there is no problem just read the cordova\phonegap docs step by step.

Comment: Yes exactly..Then how can build with out cloud

Comment: like I said your code is visible even if you not using intel...anyone can see your code

Answer (score 1):

As you, I needed to build locally my application, principally to debug once Intel XDK, at least in the version 1621, does not provide support to load third-party-plugins(eg: PhoneGap Push Plugin) on Intel App Preview debug mode. Another problem was generate an iPhone build for beta tests.

My solution was, as the others suggested,  to create an similar cordova project and copy the main files from my Intel XDK Project, www folder to be more specific. Config files will be found in platforms folder once you build using cordova/phonegap.

It allowed me to build for android on my machine. Debug was easy using "Chrome Inspect" because cordova generates an debug-unaligned.apk. 
Allowed me to have access to the iOS build files, this is a good thing to do if you want to build using Xcode instead.

I Hope it help you.